# Pattern to deal with 'this' in JavaScript event handlers

Tags: javascript, this

I'm trying to encapsulate some code to grab and release the onLoad event for a tab in a Firefox Extension such that as necessary, I call:

```
var onLoad = new MyHandler_onLoad();
```

And then when I'm done, I call:

```
onLoad.unregister();
```

In principle, this code implements the above fine until you delve in to the grittier details.

```
function bind(scope, fn) {
    return function(){
    fn.apply(scope, arguments);
};

function MyHandler_onLoad()
{
    this.scan = function() {
        do_scan(this.browser); // this.browser == undefined
    };

    this.register = function() {
        this.tab.addEventListener("load", this.scan, false);
    };

    this.unregister = function() {
        this.tab.removeEventListener("load", this.scan, false);
    };  

    this.tab = gBrowser.selectedTab;
    this.browser = gBrowser.selectedBrowser;
    this.register();
    window.addEventListener("unload", bind(this, this.unregister), false);
};
```

Due to the behaviour of JavaScript's `this`, I'm struggling. I want to be able to access this.browser from my scan function, but can't.

I've used `bind` to ensure that `unregister` gains the appropriate context on `unload`. But, I can't do this with the call to `scan` as I'll not be able to remove it later if I don't have a name.

**Is there a good pattern for doing this sort of thing in JavaScript?**

I've tried storing the result of bind(this, this.scan) as a variable in the constructor, but it doesn't help and am now struggling for options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this`, in JavaScript, always points to *the current object*.  If there is no current object, `this` points to `window`, which is *always* the top-level scope (in a browser anyway)

By example:

```
function(){
   ...
   this.foo = function(){
      this;
      // There is no object here, so `this` points to `window`
   }
}
```

---

```
function foo(){
    this;
    // again, no object so `this` points to window`
}
foo();
```

---

```
function foo(){
    this;
    // because initialized with `new`, `this` points to an instance of `foo`
    this.bar = function(){
       this;
       // no object, `this` points to `window`
    }
}
var foobar = new foo();
// above is roughly equivalent to: foo.apply({}, arguments);  Note the new object

foobar.bar();
```

---

```
var foo = {
   bar : function(){
      this;
      // `this` points at `foo` -- note the object literal
   }
};
```

---

```
function foo(){
}
foo.prototype.bar = function(){
    this;
    // `this` points to the instance of `foo`
}
var foobar = new foo();
foobar.bar();
```

---

The concept of *binding* allows you to lock the `this` variable to whatever you want since the final call to the function is via `.apply(scope, params)`, so going back to your original question, my last example above will work, so will this:

```
function foo(){
    this.scan = bind(this, function(){
       this;
       // `this` points to instance of `foo` IF `foo` is instantiated
       // with `new` keyword.
    });
}
new foo()
```

If you want to understand all of this more, I have two articles I wrote ages back that should help:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3600451/Javascript-Basics-Part-8.htm
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3606701/Javascript-Basics-Part-9.htm

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Don't use `this`.

Here is an alternative way to define `MyHandler_onLoad`

```
function MyHandler_onLoad() {
    var onload_handler = {
        scan: function() {
            do_scan(onload_handler.browser); // onload_handler.browser == undefined
        },
        register = function() {
            onload_handler.tab.addEventListener("load", onload_handler.scan, false);
        },
        unregister = function() {
            onload_handler.tab.removeEventListener("load", onload_handler.scan, false);
        }
    };
    onload_handler.tab = gBrowser.selectedTab;
    onload_handler.browser = gBrowser.selectedBrowser;
    onload_handler.register();
    window.addEventListener("unload", bind(onload_handler, onload_handler.unregister), false);
    return onload_handler;
}
```

Even better? Move global dependencies up and no access to tab and browser properties (ie making them 'private')

You could even choose to hide register and unregister functions as I'm not sure you even need them, since it seems to attach itself already.

```
var handler = MyHandler_onLoad(gBrowser.selectedTab, gBrowser.selectedBrowser);

function MyHandler_onLoad(tab, browser) {
    var onload_handler = {
        scan: function() {
            do_scan(browser); // browser == undefined
        },
        register = function() {
            tab.addEventListener("load", onload_handler.scan, false);
        },
        unregister = function() {
            tab.removeEventListener("load", onload_handler.scan, false);
        }
    };
    onload_handler.register();
    window.addEventListener("unload", bind(onload_handler, onload_handler.unregister), false);
    return onload_handler;
}
```

Specifically your problem with `this` is that it points to the scan function, not your handler object. If you don't use `this` at all then you will never run into these kinds of bugs.

Oh, and you don't need to use `new` either.

Comment: That seems to solve it, but I presume I do need to use new as I want to handle multiple tabs each in a separate MyHandler_onLoad object.

Comment: @Mat, yes you no longer need 'new'. You should only use 'new' when you're going for a prototype approach, which is no longer the recommended approach (as OO is no longer the recommended appraoch)

Answer (score 1):

```
function MyHandler_onLoad()
{
    var self = this;
```

Having done this, `self` will always point to the correct object in your handlers.